# Which GEO data format does this data represent

Tags: coordinate-system, sql-server, web-service, json

I am parsing GIS data from a ESRI webservice in which I get the data specified as the following in a JSON file

```
"geometryType" : "esriGeometryPoint",
"spatialReference" : {
"wkid" : 102100
```

an example of the data provided has the following look

```
"geometry" : {
    "x" : 1734891.0457560429,
    "y" : 5740400.9625475956
  }
```

I don't usually work with GIS data so I am not sure what I am doing.
I want to store it in a SQL server DB as a GeoGrapy datatype which requires values between [-90, 90] and [-180, 180] degrees.

How Do I convert these coordinates. I do not know which format it is so I can not search for transformation equations.

could it be wgs84?

(The location is in Europe)

Comment: Here's one way of converting the geometry: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.geometry.webmercatorutils.html#webmercatortogeographic

Answer (score 1):

I just googled "wkid 102100" and it took me to

http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/esri102100/

which should hopefully give you what you need.

Comment: found this too. I'm a GIS newbie so I need to do a LOOOOOOT of research. I still don't see how to make this transformation from one to the other. I have no control over the esri side. I have to make this conversion localy

Comment: One way would be to download QGIS (free GIS software)

Comment: I'll give it a try ;)

Comment: How are you getting this data in the first place?  It's possible to specify the result SRS as 4326.  See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/query.html

Comment: Just a streamlined collection JSON objects. In the meantime I found out that it is supossed to be epsg3765 (hrts96/tm)

Answer (score 0):

`WKID: 102100` is also known as WGS84 Web (or Pseudo) Mercator, or also known as **EPSG:3857**. It's a Mercator variant where it uses the spheroid formula but the lat/longs are ellipsoidal, and thus isn't conformal.

If you'd like to try to do your own conversion, read the [EPSG Guidance Note 7-2](http://www.epsg.org/guides/G7-2.html), and you'll find the Pseudo-Mercator formula on page 40.

Comment: I just found out that it is supossed to be EPSG 3765. now I just need to find a way to convert it. I wonder how similar it is to 3857

Comment: would you recommend to use gdal for the purpose of transforming it.
If I would be using the geometry instead of the geography datatype in sql server i might store it instead of transforming it into LAT/LONG